# Replace more than two line break with a single line break

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to replace more than 2 line breaks in the user input with one single break, also this has to work on all operating systems. the code that i have put together using some examples on SO is as follows:

```
$post_desc = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", "\n", $post_desc);
$post_desc = nl2br($post_desc);
```

But this is only replacing every line break with only a single one even if it is more than one meaning i need it to replace more than one line breaks into only one. Target is to show paragraphs as paragraphs and replace multiple line breaks between paragraphs in a single one.

Please guide.

Comment: @coder an example along with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([\r\n]){2,}
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.This will only replace linebreaks more than `2`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing duplicate linebreaks and after replace all linebreaks with a `<br>`, why you don't do it in one step:

```
$post_desc = preg_replace('/\R+/', '<br>', $post_desc);
```